# Esempio di subordinata causale attraverso la semplice giustapposizione

Tags: grammar, grammatical-analysis

Leggo sul mio libro di grammatica che nell'analisi del periodo, la subordinata causale può anche risultare dalla semplice giustapposizione tra frasi, senza un perchè che la introduce. Secondo voi questo potrebbe essere un esempio corretto? Il perchè non è esplicito, però se lo metto la frase ha perfettamente senso. 
Si tratta quindi di una subordinata causale? O sbaglio? Avete altri esempi che chiarificano questa cosa?

*"Oggi io e mio papà abbiamo fatto i mestieri. Non avevamo scelta, **DOMANI VIENE LA NONNA A PRENDERE IL TÈ DA NOI**."*

Oggi io e mio papà abbiamo fatto i mestieri. Non avevamo scelta, *perchè* DOMANI VIENE LA NONNA A PRENDERE IL TÈ DA NOI.

Answer (score 1):

Questo [articolo dell'Enciclopedia dell'Italiano Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/frasi-subordinate_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/)
contiene alcuni esempi di subordinate causali attraverso la giustapposizione di frasi:

> Le relazioni tra frasi sono relazioni concettuali che collegano processi completi. Un esempio è la causa (➔ [*causalità, espressione della*](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/espressione-della-causalita_(Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano)/)). Quando diciamo:
>
> (22) il fiume è straripato perché è piovuto a lungo
>
> consideriamo due processi entrambi saturi, completi (*è piovuto a lungo*; *il fiume è straripato*) e li colleghiamo con una relazione che ha un contenuto concettuale: la causa.
>
> [...]
>
> La seguente lista di forme esemplifica diverse strategie di
>   espressione della causa, alcune grammaticali, altre testuali,
>   caratterizzate da gradi diversi di codifica:
>
> (25) la neve si è sciolta perché il föhn ha soffiato tutta la notte
>
> (26) dopo che ha soffiato il föhn, la neve si è sciolta
>
> (27) il föhn ha soffiato tutta la notte e la neve si è sciolta
>
> (28) il föhn ha soffiato tutta la notte: la neve si è sciolta
>
> (29) il föhn ha soffiato tutta la notte; per questo la neve si è sciolta
>
> (30) il föhn ha soffiato tutta la notte: a causa di ciò, la neve si è sciolta
>
> Le frasi complesse (25) e (26) e la coordinazione (27) impongono ai
>   processi atomici una struttura grammaticale unitaria. Gli esempi (28-30)
>   sono giustapposizioni di frasi autonome: la relazione si instaura in
>   regime di coerenza testuale. Solo (30) codifica in modo totale e univoco
>   una relazione di causa, grazie alla presenza del nome *causa*. In (25), la congiunzione *perché* è compatibile anche con i motivi, e la causa è inferita. Lo stesso si può dire della locuzione anaforica *per questo* presente in (29). In (26) è codificata una relazione di successione temporale, e la causa è inferita. In (27) e (28) la causa è completamente inferita. È sullo sfondo di questo ventaglio di opzioni diverse che il periodo contenente una subordinata causale trova il suo
>   posto.

Quindi, nelle frasi (28), (29) e (30), la proposizione "il föhn ha soffiato tutta la notte" diventa una subordinata causale attraverso la giustapposizione.

Prendendo il tuo esempio, possiamo costruire alcune frasi simili agli esempi precedenti per esprimere la causa:

- Non avevamo scelta perché domani viene la nonna a prendere il tè da noi.
- Domani viene la nonna a prendere il tè da noi; per questo non avevamo scelta.
- Domani viene la nonna a prendere il tè da noi: a causa di ciò, non avevamo scelta.

Secondo me, la tua frase messa nel suo contesto è un esempio di quello che spiega l'Enciclopedia Treccani nel brano sopra citato: la relazione di causa "si instaura in regime di coerenza testuale".